# Custom Price Management in Magento

Tags: magento

I am selling certain items on my store say Blank T-shirts for which the buyer can opt for text-printing (maximum 7 letters) for additional price. How I would like this to be implemented is as follows:

Beneath the regular price there is a checkbox that says "`custom Printing`". If that `checkbox` is selected then a `textbox` shows up wherein he can enter upto 7 letters for printing. The additional cost is then reflected in his cart as a separate `item/included item`.

In the `backend` also - in the invoice I can clearly see the text that he submitted for custom printing.

Is there some option already existing in magento to handle this type of customization?
If not, then is there a popular plugin to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of a custom option.  On the edit product page in the admin visit the 'custom options' tab and you'll find what you are looking for.  The only difference from your request is that it does not add a separate item.

There are a few extensions out there that provide advanced options (import/export, grouped options, etc) if you have a large number of products that require it a custom option.